# Set NTP server in windows7 but dynamic ip

Tags: ntp

I try to set NTP server in windows7.
on client side as usual we need to set the server's IP.

the problem is Server side always have different ip everyweek I suppose.

any one can throw me a bone here?

Answer (score 0):

Good NTP servive: [pool.ntp.org](http://pool.ntp.org). Choosing pool.ntp.org as a NTP host will automatically select a well performing server. Read more at the same address (pool.ntp.org). 
This will put a light on your problem since this site also gets you different IPs every now and then.